# REST communicate between docker services in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to establish communication between docker swarm services with servie name

below are files and command

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app-ui:
    image: app-ui:v1
    networks:
      - "frontend"
      - "backend"
    ports: 
      - "9000:8080"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      
  app-svc1:
    image: app-svc1:v1
    networks:
      - "backend"
    ports: 
      - "9001:8080"
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
      
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: overlay
    name: frontend-nw 
  backend:
    driver: overlay
    name: backend-nw
```

I am deploying this with a command

> docker stack deploy --compose-file ./test-docker-stack-file.yml test_deply

```
docker service ls

ID             NAME                   MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE          PORTS
7ts7re4eynsi   test_deploy_app-svc1   replicated   4/4        app-svc1:v1   *:9001->8080/tcp
3hnmcs56hrzi   test_deploy_app-ui     replicated   1/1        app-ui:v1     *:9000->8080/tcp
```

I am trying to access app-svc1 from app-ui by a rest call on **http://test_deploy_app-svc1:9001/path****.

it is not working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

when you use service name use also "service port"

```
http://app-svc1:8080/path**
```